# Layout UI no longer triggering java code

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on a simple project as part of my mobile development class. My Project was working fine, however, after creating an activity for landscape view both activities stopped triggering the java code. I removed the layout-land folder from the project and still my original layout activity does not trigger the java code.

My suspicion is that the link between the two is broken but eclipse does not report it as an error. the setContentView() function calls the right xml and the tools:context calls the right java. What am I missing?

here is the onCreate:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

        // assign objects to java variables
        teValue1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.teValue1);
        teValue2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.teValue2);
        tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
        btPlus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btPlus);
        btMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btMinus);
        btMultiply = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btMultiply);
        btDivide = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btDivide);
        btAbout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btAbout);

        // Add on click listeners
        btPlus.setOnClickListener(new Add());
        btMinus.setOnClickListener(new Subtract());
        btMultiply.setOnClickListener(new Multiply());
        btDivide.setOnClickListener(new Divide());

    }
```

One of the click listeners:

```
private class Add implements OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!teValue1.getText().toString().matches("")
                    && !teValue1.getText().toString().matches(".")
                    && !teValue2.getText().toString().matches("")
                    && !teValue2.getText().toString().matches(".")) {
                double operand1 = Double.parseDouble(teValue1.getText()
                        .toString());
                double operand2 = Double.parseDouble(teValue2.getText()
                        .toString());
                Double result = operand1 + operand2;
                tvResult.setText(result.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

And the Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="cs325.matheson.calculator.CalculatorActivity" >

    // UI items are here...

    <requestFocus />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try clean and build your project from `project -> clean` menu

Comment: not triggering the java code, what u mean by that

Comment: code for click listeners?

Comment: Code from one of the click listeners added. NOTE: these were working and were not changed.

Comment: Panther: I mean that the the the behavior for buttons defined in the java code is no longer being triggered. i.e. a button pressed does nothing even though there are onclicklisteners defined for the button.

Answer (score 0):

The if condition in the onClick methods were never returning true. I modified them and now it works. What confuses me is why they worked before and then stopped working.